# Is there a way to get the hours from a Date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

My API passes a datetime string like `2022-04-23T11:48:18.568507` into the code.

It can be parsed but when I try to `getMinutes()` or `getHours()` on it it doesn't work and gives an error:

```
TypeError: this is not a date object at Object.getHours()
```

How can I fix this? If you suggest moment.js can you tell me how to import it?

```js
return (
            <>
            {posts.map(post => {
                const mapped_post = (
                    <div className="feed-item">
                        <div className="feed-item-header">
                            <div className="feed-item-header-left">
                                <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div className="feed-item-header-right">
                                <div className="feed-item-header-right-top">
                                    <Link to={`/users/${post.author}`}>
                                        <h3>{post.author}</h3>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                                <div className="feed-item-header-right-bottom">
                                    <p>Today at {Date.prototype.getHours(new Date(post.date_time))}:{Date.prototype.getMinutes(new Date(post.date_time))}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="feed-item-body">
                            <p>{post.content}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
                return mapped_post;
            })}
            </>
        );
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you call `new Date(post.date_time).getHours()`?

Comment: I was looking at the mozilla docs and just followed what it said https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours but that does appear to work thanks!

Comment: (Tangential, but personally, I'd move that manipulation outside of the `mapped_post` creation.)

Comment: All right, it does seem to work now!

Comment: Everything shown in the docs calls `getHours()` on the date.

Comment: I am dumb. Sorry. I was looking at the page title. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not "dumb", just maybe read down a little further ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244138/discussion-between-westsi-and-dave-newton).

Comment: *Date.prototype.getHours* expects to be called with a *Date* instance as its *this*. Calling it as `Date.prototype.getHours(...)` sets its *this* to the built–in *Date* constructor/function/object, which isn't a *Date* instance. To call it that way, use *call*: `Date.prototype.getHours.call(new Date(post.date_time))`. But of course that doesn't make sense, do what @DaveNewton said.